# Update bindingsource based on textbox for insert

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle

I'm confused on how inserts are supposed to work with datasets, bindingsources, and bound controls.

Consider the scenario:  I have a form that has either a add or update mode.  The update mode is easy, a primary key is passed into the the form, the dateset is populated, and the bindingsource is updated from the dataset.  The code looks like this.

```
Me.DS_Edit_Phantom_Block_taPhantomBlock1.Fill(Me.DS_Edit_Phantom_Block1.PHANTOM_BLOCK, CInt(mPhntmSessionNum))
        bsPhantomBlock.DataSource = DS_Edit_Phantom_Block1.PHANTOM_BLOCK
```

Inserts are proving much more difficult.  I can get a primary key from the next_sequence function (I am using oracle), but the resultant set is blank.

What I want to do is have the  user populate the needed forms then click OK, and in the click event, do the binding.

I can't make heads or tails of it though.  I can't seem to get the data (which is required due to foreign key constraints) that user inputs back into the dataset, whithout going through every single control.

Here is what I have that does not work.  It crashes when doing the Update, due to the foreign key constraints...so I need the data from the controls to get to the dataset somehow, hopefully not by manually getting each piece of data.

```
Dim drvPhantomBlock As DataRowView = TryCast(Me.bsPhantomBlock.Current, DataRowView)
    Dim drvPhantom As DataRowView = TryCast(Me.bsPhantom.Current, DataRowView)
    If mViewAddEdit = ViewAddEditEnum.Add Then ' do this first
        drvPhantomBlock = DirectCast(bsPhantomBlock.AddNew(), DataRowView)
        Dim drPhantomBlock As DataRow = drvPhantomBlock.Row
        drPhantomBlock("PHNTM_SESSION_NO") = mPhntmSessionNum
        drPhantomBlock("PHANTOM_BLOCK_NO") = mPhntmBlockNum
        drvPhantomBlock.EndEdit()
        Me.DS_Edit_Phantom_Block_taPhantomBlock1.Update(DS_Edit_Phantom_Block1.PHANTOM_BLOCK)
        bsPhantomBlock.DataSource = Me.DS_Edit_Phantom_Block_taPhantomBlock1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are doing.  When I need to add a row to the binding source I use the bindingsource.addnew() method and cast a row to the current property of the binding source.  Here is some pseudo code that is what I use:
     bs.AddNew()

```
        Dim mydv As DataRowView = bs.Current
        Dim myrow As DataRow = mydv.Row
      myrow(field1) = textbox1
      myrow(field2) = textbox2
myrow.EndEdit()
bs.EndEdit 'not sure if its necessary
Tableadapter.update(DS.UnderlyingTable)
```